# The relative motion of the points about the common center of mass

Tags: plotting, graphics

There are 2 points with masses m1 and m2, their common center of mass
  rC,r1 and r2 their radius vectors, r=Abs[r1-r2]. I built a trajectory of both material points, as well as their common center of mass in a fixed coordinate system. I need to build a trajectory of relative motion of the particles m1 and m2 around their common center of mass. All data are available.

```
m1 = 2; m2 = 3;
rCx[t_] = 26/5 + (2*t)/5;
rCy[t_] = 2/5 + (14*t)/5;
rCz[t_] = 2/5;
rx[t_] = -8 - t;
ry[t_] = -1 + 3 t;
rz[t_] = 0;
r1x[t_] = 10 + t; r2x[t_] = 2; r1y[t_] = 1 + t; r2y[t_] = 4 t; 
r1z[t_] = 2/5; r2z[t_] = 2/5;
ParametricPlot3D[{{r2x[t], r2y[t], r2z[t]}, {r1x[t], r1y[t], 
   r1z[t]}, {rCx[t], rCy[t], rCz[t]}}, {t, 0, 34}]
```

It's first, how build second?

Comment: Use Galileo transform, directly subtract the coordinates, plot it.

Comment: `Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{{r2x[t], r2y[t], r2z[t]} - {rCx[t], rCy[t], 
     rCz[t]}, {r1x[t], r1y[t], r1z[t]} - {rCx[t], rCy[t], 
     rCz[t]}}, {t, 0, i}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 30}, {-70, 50}, {0, 1}}], {i, 0.1, 34}]` for less code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your task, you need to switch you center of coordinates to point associated with center of mass and plot the radius-vectors in this coordinate system:

```
r1n = {r1x[#] - rCx[#], r1y[#] - rCy[#], r1z[#] - rCz[#]} &;
r2n = {r2x[#] - rCx[#], r2y[#] - rCy[#], r2z[#] - rCz[#]} &;
ParametricPlot3D[{r1n[t], r2n[t]}, {t, 0, 34}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

The center of mass (new center of coordinates) will be at {0,0,0}.

You can visualize the movement by this code:

```
bg = ParametricPlot3D[{{r2x[t], r2y[t], r2z[t]}, {r1x[t], r1y[t], 
     r1z[t]}, {rCx[t], rCy[t], rCz[t]}}, {t, 0, 34}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}];
bg2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r1n[t], r2n[t]}, {t, 0, 34}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}];
Manipulate[
 Row@{Show[bg,
    Graphics3D[{
      Darker[Blue, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[{rCx[tt], rCy[tt], rCz[tt]}],
      Darker[Green, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[{r1x[tt], r1y[tt], r1z[tt]}],
      Darker[Red, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[{r2x[tt], r2y[tt], r2z[tt]}],
      Black, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{{rCx[tt], rCy[tt], rCz[tt]}, {r1x[tt], r1y[tt], r1z[tt]}}],
      Black, Arrow[{{rCx[tt], rCy[tt], rCz[tt]}, {r2x[tt], r2y[tt], r2z[tt]}}]}],
    ImageSize -> 400
    ],
   Show[bg2,
    Graphics3D[{
      Darker[Blue, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0, 0}],
      Darker[Green, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[r1n[tt]],
      Darker[Red, 0.3], PointSize[0.02], Point[r2n[tt]],
      Black, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, r1n[tt]}],
      Black, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, r2n[tt]}]}],
    ImageSize -> 400
    ]
   },
 {tt, 0, 34, 0.2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]